# Transit time, United to Primera at Newark

Tags: air-travel, transit, short-connections, ewr

I am booking flights for my son, Syracuse to Newark dep 19:35  arr 20:58 (United),
then Newark to London Stansted dep 22.50 (Primera Air). This is in May. Will there be enough time for him ?

Comment: You're booking two separate tickets, right? Since United and Primera Air have no relationship.

Comment: yes two separate flights

Comment: Is your son an experienced traveller?  Has he ever flown internationally before?  I *might* use that itinerary for myself if the price was right and I wasn't traveling with checked bags, but I probably wouldn't recommend it to someone who had rarely flown domestically or who had never flown internationally.

Comment: Hi Thanks Michael, yes he has flown backwards and forwards over the last 3 years to JFK, first time to EWR. So have booked an earlier flight to give him more time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection is technically not possible, if you have luggage.
Even if you ‘fly’ out of the plane to the luggage belt, grab your stuff, and continue to the check-in counter of the other airline, you *need to check your luggage two hours before the offical start time for international flights*. So you are already late before you landed.

With no luggage, it is easily possible; unless there is significant delay, you probably have 90% chance to make it. Make sure to have your boarding pass for the second flight before you enter the first.

As others mentioned, if there is a delay, you blew the full cost for the second roundtrip. You have no regress rights against anyone.

Comment: Do you have a source for needing to check-in 2 hours before the flight? [This Primera page](https://primeraair.com/travel-info/airport-check-in/) seems to say the counter closes 45 minutes before departure, you just have to tell them online how many bags you're checking at least 2 hours before.

Comment: Primera does not say that so clear, but if you check https://primeraair.com/travel-info/airport-check-in/, all three options require it. I think it is a general regulation; I will search a bit more.

Comment: You might be right, it is a TSA recommendation, but not mandatory. _1 hour before_ is mandatory. However, the 1-hour cutoff is supposed to be _hard_, so if there is a line when you come 1:10 before, and you wait 11 minutes in line, bad luck for you. Again, that is the TSA regulation, and airlines might sometimes (illegaly) ignore it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to take a different tack from the zillion-and-one questions about making connections at Newark-Liberty to highlight an issue that does not receive much attention at TSE.

Technically speaking, United doesn't fly SYR-EWR; it contracts that route to Commutair or ExpressJet dba United Express. That isn't a problem in and of itself, but those airlines operate so-called regional jets. As these are small planes, these flights are generally the **first to suffer delays or cancellations** for anything from a mid-afternoon thunderstorm to air traffic congestion, and Newark is in the most congested airspace in the country.

Second, **Primera [does not offer online check-in for Newark departures](https://primeraair.com/travel-info/airport-check-in/)** at this writing, and does not even offer self-service kiosks. Therefore, your son would need to exit the secure area after arriving (almost certainly at Terminal A), take the AirTrain to Terminal B, wait in line for check-in and document review at the Primera counter, then proceed back to TSA screening to get to the boarding gate.

Without checked luggage, this might be possible, but there is no margin for error. If there is any kind of flow control program in effect, if the ground services are short-staffed and there is a delay before the plane can park at the gate or allow passengers to disembark, if your son accidentally boards a train going the wrong direction, this will all make for an extremely stressful experience.

And because you would be buying the two tickets separately, as Primera does not have any partnerships with other airlines, you are assuming 100% of the risk. If there is a freak blizzard and your son misses the connection, Primera has no obligations to him. He is a no-show, and under the [Conditions of Carriage](https://primeraair.com/about-us/terms-and-conditions/) you agree to when you purchase the ticket, the seat is forfeit. Most of the larger international carriers will, as a customer service gesture, let you stand by on a later flight, but ultra low-cost carriers are not known for their customer service.

I would allow **ample** time, four hours at a minimum. Airports are stressful enough as it is; there's little to be gained by adding to it with tight scheduling.

Comment: *"Primera does not offer online check-in for Newark departures at this writing"* — At this writing, Primera doesn't even *fly* to EWR.  Service begins in April.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Ha! Well, that's why it doesn't appear on all terminal lists, either. I'll have to keep an eye on this one and update once more details are released.

Answer (score 2):

If this were a single ticket (you can have multiple flights on one ticket, but a single transaction with airlines that interline), 1:48 is sufficient time (depending on your tolerance for delays and the consequences of not making it to London as planned). However, with two separate bookings, it's risky, especially if he has any checked luggage.

With separate bookings, you are arranging your own connection and are responsible for the consequences. If his first flight is delayed, the second airline will not care, and you'll be responsible for the cost of a new flight, which can be substantial, along with expenses during the delay, potentially overnight. If your son has any checked luggage, he'll have to go to baggage claim, wait for the bags, and check them in for his next flight. And at Newark, he'll likely have to change terminals and go through security again. All of that will take a fair amount of time, more-so if he's unfamiliar with the airport or not an experienced traveler.

In short, I would not do this.

Comment: Thanks Zach, have booked the earlier flight from Syracuse, giving him 5 at least 5 hours